# Access @Environment instances from within a ViewModel

Tags: arrays, swiftui

I'm attempting to follow the @Environment documentation here:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/environment

As per the docs, I can create an instance of a class within the App model and can access that from within a View. For example:

```
@main
struct ExampleApp: App {
    @State private var authenticationManager = AuthenticationManager()
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ExampleView()
                .environment(authenticationManager)
        }
    }
}
struct ExampleView: View {
    @Environment (AuthenticationManager.self) var authenticationManager
    var body: some View {
        Text(authenticationManager.username)
    }
}
```

This works, however my example is slightly more complex in that I want to use a ViewModel class to control the view.

```
struct ExampleView: View {
    let viewModel = ExampleViewModel()
    @Environment (AuthenticationManager.self) var authenticationManager
    var body: some View {
        Text(authenticationManager.getUsername())
    }
}
```

The problem, is that I can't use the same `@Environment` macro to access the `authenticationManager` in the `ExampleViewModel`, because it's not a `View`.

```
class LoginViewModel {
    @Environment (AuthenticationManager.self) var authenticationManager
    func getUsername(): String {
        return authenticationManager.username
    }
}
```

Running this code results in the following error:

> SwiftUI/Environment+Objects.swift:32: Fatal error: No Observable object of type AuthenticationManager found. A View.environmentObject(_:) for AuthenticationManager may be missing as an ancestor of this view

> Accessing Environment<AuthenticationManager>'s value outside of being installed on a View. This will always read the default value and will not update.

Now, I could just pass the AuthenticationManager through to the ViewModel each time, but it's a bit awkward - as far as I can tell either the ViewModel is going to need to be option on the View, or the AuthenticationManager is going to need to be optional within the ViewModel.

In reality, the app is more complicated than this, and the 'Manager' classes may need to talk to other 'Manager' classes. I don't really want to be passing these things in constructors if I can help it.  The @Environment macro seemed at first glance to be a nice elegant way to share an instance of a class, I can't wrap my head around this current issue.

Is there a better way to structure the app or access these methods? I'd like to keep the code as clean and reusable as possible.

Comment: Your viewModel is a class and a single object of it may be referenced from multiple views with different environments. What about this then?

Comment: The macro is only for SwiftUI views as you know but you can use Dependency Injection to share instances of the managers without passing them as constructors. It is just a little bit of architecture.

Comment: IMO you need to rethink your architecture. Environment = some qualities of the _view's environment_. E.g. colors, screen size, etc. While you seems are trying to use it as a way to pass a manager/service class. If it's really an environment, think how to properly separate ViewModel from even needing it. If it's more of a service/manager, pass it to ViewModel on init, and don't have it as environment in view

Comment: Assuming your `AuthenticationManager` is a simple class (not ObservableObject), you could try 
making it a singleton. That way it is available everywhere (including your `ExampleViewModel`) 
and does not have to be passed around using `@Environment`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SwiftUI the `View` struct is essentially the view model already and the actual views (e.g. UIViews on iOS) are auto-generated for us based on a diff of these `View` structs. As Apple say, "the View struct should be your primary encapsulation mechanism of view data". So you would be best to keep your view data in the structs and not move it into classes. There is a lot of magic going on in the `View` struct and you would lose that if you used classes and may waste time trying to reimplement its features, this article explains some of the magic in the `View` struct: https://mobileappcircular.com/how-to-avoid-repeating-swiftui-view-updates-dcf0a65d3758

So just move the `func getUsername` into your `AuthenticationManager`, call it from an action int he View struct, e.g. `.task`, then set the result on an `@State`. If you want to group related state vars together you can make a custom struct, then you can take advantage of `didSet` and `mutating func` for logic. E.g.

```
.task {
    do {
        user = await controller.getUser()
    }
    catch {
        message = error.localizedDescription
    }
}
```